# Proof that there is no rational solutions to the equation $x^3+2x-1=0$

Tags: proof-explanation, roots, rational-numbers, cubics

Proof by contradiction:
Assuming that there is a rational solution to the equation $x^3+2x-1=0$.

Let $x=a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime with $b$ not equal to zero.

Performing a substitution into the equation, it simplifies to $a^3+2ab^2-b^3=0$.

Three cases to consider (since $a$ and $b$ are coprime so they can't be both even):

**Case 1**: $a$ is even and $b$ is odd, then

$a^3$ is even
$2ab$ is even
$b^3$ is odd

So the LHS of the equation is odd and the RHS of the equation is even. Therefore, there is a contradiction.

**Case 2**: $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, then

$a^3$ is odd
$2ab$ is even
$b^3$ is even

So the LHS of the equation is odd and the RHS of the equation is even. Therefore, there is a contradiction.

**Case 3**: $a$ and $b$ are odd, then

$a^3$ is odd
$2ab$ is even
$b^3$ is odd

So the LHS of the equation is even and the RHS of the equation is even.

So does that means that there is a rational solution when $a$ and $b$ are odd? I am stuck with this. Can someone help me out? When we perform proof by contradiction, do we have to perform it for all cases? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You've shown that if there is a rational root, then the numerator and denominator of that root are both odd. Nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), only $\pm1$ could possibly be rational roots of your polynomial, but they aren't. Therefore, it has no rational roots.

Comment: Thanks Jose but I am not quite sure how the theorem works. This is our first lesson on proof by contradiction in highschool.

Comment: @user450003 Did you read the statement of the theorem?

Comment: Yes I did and I am still confused.

Comment: @user450003 What's the problem? It says that if there was a rational root $\frac ab$, with $a\in\mathbb Z$ and $b\in\mathbb N$, then $a\mid-1$ and $b\mid 1$, which means that $\frac ab=\pm1$.

Comment: I don't understand why  a∣−1 and b∣1?

Comment: @user450003 Because the constant term of the polynomial is $-1$, because the coefficient of $x^3$ is $1$, and because that's what the theorem says.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! So for what I have done with proof by contradiction, I will still have to consider every case and make sure all cases lead to a contradiction for the proof to be valid? Am I right?

Comment: @user450003 There are only two cases to be considered: $1$ and $-1$. Since none of them is a root, a contradiction is reached.

Comment: @Jose: while that's a great solution and probably the way most people would do this question, the OP is in high school and I don't think this method is at an appropriate level for them.

Comment: @YiFan What is the point of posting this comment **ten months** after I've posted my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Much easier using the following theorem: if $f(x) = a_nx^n + \cdots a_1 x + a_0\in\Bbb Z[x]$, then
$$f(p/q) = 0 \hbox{ ($p/q$ irreducible)}\implies p\vert a_0,q\vert a_n.$$

Answer (score 1):

$a^3+2ab^2-b^3=0$ implies $a^3=(-2ab+b^2)b$ and so $b$ divides $a^3$. Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, we must have $b=\pm 1$. Then $a(a^2+2)=\pm 1$, which cannot happen because $a^2+2\ge2$ cannot divide $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I don't understand why b must be plus or minus 1.

Comment: @user450003, if $p$ is a prime dividing $b$, then $p$ divides $a$, but this cannot happen because $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: @lhf Why didn't you look at the case $b = -1 $?

Comment: @john, fixed and simplified. Thanks for the push.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation in the form $x^3+2x=1$. Suppose there is a rational solution $m/n$  with $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Such a solution can be chosen with $ n$ positive integer. 
Then we get $$ \frac{m^3}{n^3} +2\frac{m}{n} =1. $$

Multiplying by $n^3$ we get, $$m^3+2mn^2= n^3;\quad \mbox{equivalently}\quad m(m^2+2n^2) =n^3\qquad(*)$$

This shows $m$ is a factor of  $n^3$. The hypothesis $\gcd(m,n)=1$  forces to conclude $m=1$. Now putting $m=1$, in equation $(*)$ we get $$1+2n^2=n^3 $$ which can be rewritten as $n^2(n-2)=1$. This last equation contradicts the supposition that $n$ is a positive integer.   So there are no rational roots to your equation.